# Not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: java

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee employee = new Employee();

        //Prompt for and then set the first name, last name, gender, dependents
        employee.setFirstName(getInput("First Name: "));
        employee.setLastName(getInput("Last Name: "));
        employee.setGender(getInput("Gender: ").charAt(0));

        employee.setDependents(getInput("Dependents: "));
        employee.setAnnualSalary(getInput("Annual Salary: "));

        //display divider
        displayDivider("Employee Information");

        //Display the employee information
        employee.displayEmployee();
        System.out.println("Number of Employees: " + Employee.getNumEmployees());

        //Second Employee
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("Mary", "Noia", 'F' , 5 ,  24000.0);

        //display divider
        displayDivider("Employee Information");
        employee2.displayEmployee();
        System.out.println("Number of Employees: " + Employee.getNumEmployees());

    } //end of main

    public static String getInput(String inputType)
    {
        String input = "";
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the " + inputType);

        return input;

    }

    public static void displayDivider(String outputTitle)
    {

        System.out.println("*********" + outputTitle + "********");

    }//end of displayDvider

} //end of MainClass
```

This is my result. But I am suppose to get Number of employee: 2 at the end

```
*********Employee Information********
First Name: Arooba
Last Name:  Munir
Gender: F
Number of Dependents:   2
Annual Salary:  $50,000.00
Weekly Pay: $961.54
Number of Employees: 1
*********Employee Information********
First Name: Mary
Last Name:  Noia
Gender: F
Number of Dependents:   5
Annual Salary:  $24,000.00
Weekly Pay: $461.54
Number of Employees: 1
```

Comment: We are not sure what you are doing and asking

Comment: *"Not sure what I am doing wrong"* - Not actually asking a question would be the obvious thing.  Some idea of what it's suppose to do and what you expect it to do would also be nince

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Since your issue is with `Employee.getNumEmployees()`, maybe you should include the code for `Employee`, otherwise how are we supposed to know/help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put both of the employees into a arraylist and getting the size of the arraylist. I dont think that this is going to work

```
Employee.getNumEmployees();
```

So maybe something like this?

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList();
employees.add(new Employee("Mary", "Noia", 'F' , 5 ,  24000.0));
//etc...
```

Comment: Than i guess you can use a hardcoded counter.... so int counter=0, and everytime you make an employee increment that.

Comment: I dont think you can have the number of employees inside of each instance of the object because it will always be one. Unless you increment one employee objects count everytime you create a new employee but i dont think that that is the right way to do it